# File not found errors during shell script execution

Tags: shell, ftp

I am having some weird issues while running my shell script. The shell script is basically for sending a file through FTP. It takes a single parameter as file name and sends the file on the destination FTP path.

Now, when I execute the shell script using Putty, it sends the file without any problem. But, when I try to run the shell script using some external application, I am getting errors saying specified path not found. I already tried setting the path within the script and also checked the file permissions. Everything looks good. Please help me with some clues and pointers.

These are the errors I get

1. Error when I directly pass the file name.
   Myfile.csv: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
2. Error when I pass full path of the file.
   /serv/scripts/test/Myfile.csv: The system cannot find the path specified.

Following is the shell script.

```
 ftp_put()
 {
   ftp -ni server_name << EOF
   user anonymous anonymous
   cd BHU
   put $FTPFILE
   quit
   EOF
 }
 FTPFILE=$1
 ftp_put
```

Comment: From where you are running the script? if you are specifying only file name as input argument then it will search the file where your script is located. if you want to search it at actual location then provide full path as an argument.

Comment: Hi, I tried both ways. I have placed the file and the shell script in the same location. But, even if I try direct file name or full path and file name, it doesn't work. As stated, it shows the mentioned errors in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

The end word for a here-doc **must** be the **only** characters on that line. No leading or trailing whitespace allowed.

The only exception is this form: `<<-EOF`, where the end word may be preceded by **tab characters** only.

---

Your function should end like this

```
    put $FTPFILE
    quit
EOF
}
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for your input. Can you please elaborate on that? Do you mean, I should remove << -EOF from my code?

Comment: Oh, that was the code with tabs added by me. Original code doesn't have any tabs or spaces before or after.